# How to copy format of one row to another row in Excel with c#

Tags: c#, excel

I am inserting data to Excel using C#. Whenever I add a new row to Excel using C# I want the same format as above row i.e, color, font and background color everything by programmatically.

It's an OLEDB insert.

Post insert, I want to apply the format of first row to the second row. With format painter from UI it's a straightforward job, I can't find a way to do the same with C#.

Comment: are you using `insert` or `copy(, dest)`?

Comment: insert => copy => paste => clear contents

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) First you Need to get the Range you want to copy for e.g. RngToCopy
2) Then Set the Range where you want to insert.
3) use the below mentioned code snippet.

```
  Range RngToCopy = ws.get_Range(StartCell, EndCell).EntireRow;
Range RngToInsert = ws.get_Range(StartCell, Type.Missing).EntireRow;
oRngToInsert.Insert(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, oRngToCopy.Copy(Type.Missing));

//ws is the worksheet object, set StartCell and EndCell as per your requirement
```