# Copy format from one row to another using c#

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, formatting, excel-interop

This question is quite similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716370/how-to-copy-format-of-one-row-to-another-row-in-excel-with-c-sharp). But the answer given suggests copying the format along with the data. I have a excel sheet (.xlsx) that I generate using SSIS. Now I have set the formatting in first row, which I want to copy to all the rows that  are already filled in the worksheet. How can I do that using C#? I am using Excel interop.

Comment: Show the code that you use to format the first row, perhaps it can just be applied to the other rows.

Comment: I am setting the format in the first row of a template file by hand. the new rows are added to this template file and the formatting needs to be applied to these rows.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [PasteSpecial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.pastespecial.aspx) with `xlPasteFormats`.

```
Excel.Range R1 = (Excel.Range)oSheet.Cells[11, 11];
R1.Copy(Type.Missing);

Excel.Range R2 = (Excel.Range)oSheet.Cells[15, 15];
R2.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteFormats,
    Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
```

Comment: Too bad it hijacks the clipboard. Not a viable solution.

Answer (score 4):

So you want to copy *format* from first cell and apply it to all your *sheet*.

There is a way to process:

```
 Range sourceRange = sheet.get_Range("A1:A1");
 sourceRange.Copy();

 Range last = sheet.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
 Range destinationRange = sheet.get_Range("A1", last);

 destinationRange.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteFormats);
```

Comment: `System.Type.Missing` would need to be supplied for missing arguments to `PasteSpecial`.

Comment: run `PasteSpecial()` without any arguments works pretty well. So what do you mean ?

Comment: My mistake, sorry! I recalled incorrectly that C# required all arguments to be supplied when using Interop. This requirement is no longer necessary from C# 2010 (which introduced *optional parameters*).

Comment: What if I wanted to copy values of the cell in that row?

Answer (score 0):

I use it as mickro explained and it worked perfectly!!!!!

```
                Range contentAlarms =exlWsheetAlarms.get_Range("A1:G"+countList);
                contentAlarms.Copy(Type.Missing);

                Range last = exlWsheetUlt.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
                Range destinationRange = exlWsheetUlt.get_Range("B90", last);

                destinationRange.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteFormats);
```

thanks!

Comment: So you are copying from contentAlarms into last?