# Copying format of cells in a row to all populated rows below

Tags: c#, excel, webforms

We are using the AccessDatabaseEngine DLLs to read and write to an .XLSX document without opening it in Excel on the server. I'd like to copy the cell format from a row (in this case row 9) to all the rows below it that are populated.

Unfortunately we do not and will not have Office/Excel installed on the server, so using the Range class doesn't appear to be an option - [Copy format from one row to another using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542864/copy-format-from-one-row-to-another-using-c-sharp).

Has anyone done this before just using the AccessDatabaseEngine or is its functionality limited to the values in the cells only?

Any help would be duly appreciated.

Comment: I have a similar scenario i.e. I too do not have MS office on my development environment or server so no excel dlls. So I found an excel library that was very useful to me and I am still using it. You will find it here. https://code.google.com/archive/p/excellibrary/. Hope it helps you with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Samar, are you able to offer any pointers at all on using that library?
The project file contains errors in their example code and only appears to be able to write corrupt .xls files when these are corrected.
I've checked its reading potential of a small .xlsx document and this failed due to a System.OutOfMemoryException.

Were these issues you had to circumvent to get it to work?

Comment: I did not face any of the issues which you have mentioned. It worked just fine in my case. I just went through the documentation which they had there and that was it. Try creating simple excel files at first and then move on to more complex operations on it.