# c# working on excel files with large data

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

I'm copying data from first sheet of different excel files to a single workbook. I already have tried it with different alternatives like `npoi`, `spire.xls` and `Interop` which works good, but it kills too much of my time. It would really be thankful if anyone can suggest me with a better one. Been through many forms on the web, but couldn't find.

> FYI: Each of My files are more than 50 MB in size. A few being 10 MB or less.

This is one of which I have tried (Uses Spire.xls):

```
workbook = new Workbook();
//laod first file
workbook.LoadFromFile(names[0]);

//load the remaining files starting with second file
for (int i = 1; i < cnt; i++)
{
    LoadFIle(names[i]);
    //merge the loaded file immediately and than load next file
    MergeData();
}

private void LoadFIle(string filePath)
{
     //load other workbooks starting with 2nd workbbook
     tempbook = new Workbook();
     tempbook.LoadFromFile(filePath);
}

private void MergeData()
{
    try
    {
        int c1 = workbook.ActiveSheet.LastRow, c2 = tempbook.Worksheets[0].LastRow;

        //check if you have exceeded 1st sheet limit
        if ((c1 + c2) <= 1048575)
        {
           //import the second workbook's worksheet into the first workbook using a datatable
           //load 1st sheet of tempbook into sheet
           Worksheet sheet = tempbook.Worksheets[0];
           //copy data from sheet into a datatable
           DataTable dataTable = sheet.ExportDataTable();
           //load sheet1
           Worksheet sheet1 = workbook.Worksheets[workbook.ActiveSheetIndex];
           sheet1.InsertDataTable(dataTable, false, sheet1.LastRow + 1, 1);
       }
       else if ((c1 >= 1048575 && c2 >= 1048575) || c1 >= 1048575 || c2 >= 1048575 || (c1 + c2) >= 1048575)
       {
           workbook.Worksheets.AddCopy(tempbook.Worksheets[0]);
           indx = workbook.ActiveSheet.Index;
           workbook.ActiveSheetIndex = ++indx;
       }
       else
       {
           //import the second workbook's worksheet into the first workbook using a datatable
          //load 1st sheet of tempbook into sheet
           Worksheet sheet = tempbook.Worksheets[0];
           //copy data from sheet into a datatable
           DataTable dataTable = sheet.ExportDataTable();
           //load sheet1
           Worksheet sheet1 = workbook.Worksheets[workbook.ActiveSheetIndex];
           sheet1.InsertDataTable(dataTable, false, sheet1.LastRow + 1, 1);
      }
   }
   catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
   {

   }
}
}
```

Well, this works good but as said takes a long time. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I realise this is not the answer you want, but why are you manipulating large data sets in a spreadsheet?  Databases are good at this task.  Excel can query a database if you need to pull data into a sheet.

Comment: @Neil: That's client requirements. Can't help out. And these files are also from client side.

Comment: Clients can be wrong.  You need to be pushing back and saying "either it will take a long time, or you should do it 'this' way and it will be quicker".

Comment: 50MB is *not* a lot of data. Excel can work with *many* millions of rows of data using PowerPivot. It's the same compressed in-memory columnstore engine used by SSAS. Excel's PowerQuery is almost a full ETL tool that can *easily* merge data from multiple sources, including databases, Hadoop etc. Merging Excel sources is very easy

Comment: I guess you are using .xls files rather than .xlsx? Excel interop can be fast too, more so when you just want to copy the contents. Like select the range, copy it into an array, select the range in the new sheet and paste it there. This is pretty basic stuff. Its like you said: "There is a Solution, but it takes 1 day time to learn, so i dont try, show me a better one"

Comment: What are you trying to do? Concatenate two sources? Match between them?

Comment: @FrankM Interop is the slowest way possible. It requires one slow COM operation for *every* property or method access. People use libraries so they *don't* have to use Interop

Comment: @FrankM: I'm working on both .xls as well as .xlsx.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Yup! I'm trying to concatenate and match.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava `xls` was abandoned 12 years ago. Do you *really* want to work with that deprecated format? It's only needed to support Excel 2003 and older versions

Comment: @Neil: You're right but there millions of such files and porting it to DB at a time isn't that easy.

Comment: @AshishSrivastava yup what? What kind of matching?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Sorry, but starting excel and loading a file takes time, but not extracting the data. So from my experience, you are wrong. For OpenXML (xlsx) you are right, naturally ;)

Comment: @FrankM you misunderstood what I said. With interop, any operation is a COM+ operation which means every operation takes orders of magnitude more than a direct property access. You probably haven't tried manipulating Excel files on the *server* either, where Interop is a sure way to kill memory and leave ghost instances running in the background

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If you release all objects and close excel gracefully, nothing will retain.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: as I said, interop was my first choice but to be frank it takes more time than Spire.xls and npoi.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my (fastest I know of) implementation using Excel interop. Although I looked carefully to release all (must have missed one), 2 Excel instances remain in the processes list, they are closed after the program ends.

The key is to only have 2 Open Excel instances and to copy the data as a Block using `Range.Value2`.

```
//Helper function to cleanup
public void ReleaseObject(object obj)
{
    if (obj != null && Marshal.IsComObject(obj))
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
    }
}


public void CopyIntoOne(List<string> pSourceFiles, string pDestinationFile)
{

    var sourceExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    var destinationExcelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

    // TODO: Check if it exists
    destinationExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(pDestinationFile);
    // for debug
    //destinationExcelApp.Visible = true;
    //sourceExcelApp.Visible = true;
    int i = 0;
    var sheets = destinationExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets;
    var lastsheet = destinationExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[sheets.Count];
    ReleaseObject(sheets);
    foreach (var srcFile in pSourceFiles)
    {
        sourceExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(srcFile);
        // get extends
        var lastRow = sourceExcelApp.ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, XlSearchOrder.xlByRows,
            XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        var lastCol = sourceExcelApp.ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value, XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, XlSearchDirection.xlPrevious, false,
            System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        var startCell = (Range) sourceExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        var endCell = (Range) sourceExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells[lastRow.Row, lastCol.Column];
        var myRange = sourceExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range[startCell, endCell];
        // copy the values
        var value = myRange.Value2;

        // create sheet in new Workbook at the end                
        Worksheet newSheet = destinationExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After: lastsheet);
        ReleaseObject(lastsheet);
        lastsheet = newSheet;
        //its even faster when adding it at the front
        //Worksheet newSheet = destinationExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add();

        // change that to a good name
        newSheet.Name = ++i + "";

        var dstStartCell = (Range) destinationExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells[1, 1];
        var dstEndCell = (Range) destinationExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells[lastRow.Row, lastCol.Column];
        var dstRange = destinationExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range[dstStartCell, dstEndCell];
        // this is the actual paste
        dstRange.Value2 = value;
        //cleanup

        ReleaseObject(startCell);
        ReleaseObject(endCell);
        ReleaseObject(myRange);
        ReleaseObject(value);// cannot hurt, but not necessary since its a simple array
        ReleaseObject(dstStartCell);
        ReleaseObject(dstEndCell);
        ReleaseObject(dstRange);
        ReleaseObject(newSheet);
        ReleaseObject(lastRow);
        ReleaseObject(lastCol);
        sourceExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Close(false);

    }
    ReleaseObject(lastsheet);

    sourceExcelApp.Quit();
    ReleaseObject(sourceExcelApp);
    destinationExcelApp.ActiveWorkbook.Save();
    destinationExcelApp.Quit();
    ReleaseObject(destinationExcelApp);

    destinationExcelApp = null;
    sourceExcelApp = null;

}
```

I have tested it on small excel files and are curious how it behaves with larger files.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround buddy! But this doesn't works. It copies each sheet of the source file to different sheets of destination file, rather than appending it into one single sheet. Copying a sheet to another workbook is pretty simple and obviously fast. But I'm copying each sheet data one below the other in the destination sheet by retaining its format and every single detail.

Comment: Well it should be easy to adjust it to do excactly that. Just "move" the start ```dstStartCell``` and ```dstEndCell``` of the Range for the target to the current position and remove the "adding" logic of the sheet. This will be even faster because no new sheet is appended(1 less COM+ operation per input file). How long did it take for your big data?

Comment: Well copying the format and every single detail(whatever this means) was not part of your question, but copying the format is not more than a few commands, see here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18543010/1037841 There is also a Method ```Range.Copy``` and ```Range.Paste```  which woudn't be much slower. For General information imagine, what a user would do achieving the result and then remodelling the steps. Might be: select all, click copy, scroll to the last line, click paste. Interop does this as instant as the user would experience it.

Comment: Well as you said, the solution works pretty good for small files. But it gets hanged for files larger than 5 MB.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. Please post your solution, when your find one, since this is an interesting matter.

Comment: Surely buddy! But I have 1 doubt in your solution. Curious to know, while copying, what if the row count exceeds 1048576 which is actually the last row of any excel sheet? If you don't mind can you please paste a sample code to add a new sheet when the row count exceeds the limit?

Comment: Firstly, the last row of xls sheets is 65536. And second, if you reach the end of one sheet, you need to split the data, inserting the first part in the old and then the second in the new. I think you have everything you need to program your solution: Selecting Ranges, copying them, pasting them, adding a new sheet. You just need to put it together...

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that.