# How to apply cell style to each cell in new row from previous row

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel sheet which contains previously some values with some formatting. I would like to add a new row programmatically using c#. How can I apply styling of previous row to this newly added row during insert operation?

The code that I am using is as below:

```
Application excelApp = new Application();
            Workbooks workBooks = excelApp.Workbooks;
            Workbook workBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName, Type.Missing, false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            int nTotalSheets = workBook.Worksheets.Count;

            Worksheet workSheet = workBook.Worksheets[1];
            int nColumns = workSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
            int nRows = workSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
            workSheet.Cells[nRows + 1, 1] = "Test";
            Range excelRange = workSheet.UsedRange;
            workBook.Close(true, fileName, false);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workBook);
```

Comment: You can refer to following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716370/how-to-copy-format-of-one-row-to-another-row-in-excel-with-c-sharp

Comment: @PareshJ, the link that you gave me copies data from other excel sheet by inserting it somewhere in the middle... But I am going to enter data from an object in a new row at the end of sheet... Hence I need to know the formatting applied to previous row in each cell... I have added the code that I am using in the question above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542864/copy-format-from-one-row-to-another-using-c-sharp)

I was looking for below code:

```
            workSheet.Cells[nRows + 1, 3] = DateTime.Today;
            Range sourceRange = workSheet.Cells[nRows, 3];
            sourceRange.Copy(Type.Missing);
            Range destinationRange = workSheet.Cells[nRows + 1, 3];
            destinationRange.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteFormats, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
            destinationRange.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteFormulas, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
```

The last line is for copying formulas.