# Retain same Excel styles when merging sheets using C# and OpenXML

Tags: c#, xml, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am getting issues when merging multiple excel sheets in into one excel document in C#. So essentially its one workbook with multiple sheets. This works however

The issue being is that it is not preserving the formatting and styling. The first sheet is formatted correctly however it is copying that same style throughout the sheets when it shouldn't be.

I need help on merging the sheets and keeping the same styles and formatting.

**Loop through sheets C#**

```
// For each worksheet in the child workbook...
                    foreach (Sheet childSheet in childWorkbookSheets)
                    {
                        // Get a worksheet part for the child worksheet using
                        // it's relationship Id.
                        childWorksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)childWorkbook.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(childSheet.Id);

                        // Add a worksheet part to the merged workbook based on
                        // the child worksheet.
                        mergedWorksheetPart = mergedWorkbookPart.AddPart<WorksheetPart>(childWorksheetPart);

                        //There should be only one worksheet that is set
                        //as the main view.
                        CleanView(mergedWorksheetPart);

                        // Create a Sheet element for the new sheet in the
                        // merged workbook.
                        newMergedSheet = new Sheet();

                        // Set the Name, Id, and SheetId attributes of the
                        // new Sheet element.
                        newMergedSheet.Name = GenerateWorksheetName(mergedWorkbookSheets, childSheet.Name.Value);

                        newMergedSheet.Id = mergedWorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(mergedWorksheetPart);

                        newMergedSheet.SheetId = (uint)mergedWorkbookSheets.ChildElements.Count + 1;

                        // Add the new Sheet element to the Sheets element in the
                        // merged workbook.
                        mergedWorkbookSheets.Append(newMergedSheet);

                        // Get the SheetData element of the new worksheet part
                        // in the merged workbook.
                        mergedSheetData = mergedWorksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

                        if (styleCounter == 0)
                        {
                            mergedWorkbook.WorkbookPart.AddPart<WorkbookStylesPart>(childSharedStylePart);
                        }

                        styleCounter++;

                        // For each row of data...
                        foreach (Row row in mergedSheetData.Elements<Row>())
                        {
                            // For each cell in the row...
                            foreach (Cell cell in row.Elements<Cell>())
                            {
                                // If the cell is using a shared string, merge
                                // the string from the child workbook into the merged
                                // workbook.
                                CellFormat cellFormat = cell.StyleIndex != null ? GetCellFormat(mergedWorkbookPart, cell.StyleIndex).CloneNode(true) as CellFormat : new CellFormat();
                                GetCellFormat(mergedWorkbookPart, cell.StyleIndex);
                                if (cell.DataType != null &&
                                    cell.DataType.Value == CellValues.SharedString)
                                {
                                    ProcessCellSharedString(mergedWorksheetPart, cell, mergedSharedStringTablePart, childSharedStringTablePart);
                                }
                                cell.StyleIndex = InsertCellFormat(mergedWorkbookPart, cellFormat);

                                mergedSheetData.AppendChild(new Cell());
                                mergedCellformat = GetCellFormat(mergedWorkbookPart, cell.StyleIndex);

                                //cellFormat.ReplaceChild(mergedCellformat,mergedCellformat);

                                //attempt to add styling to the other worksheets
                                mergedCellformat.FillId.Value = (cellFormat.FillId.Value);
                                mergedCellformat.BorderId.Value = (cellFormat.BorderId.Value);
                                mergedCellformat.FontId.Value = (cellFormat.FontId.Value);
                                //mergedCellformat.FormatId = (cellFormat.FormatId.Value);

                                //cellFormat.AppendChild(mergedCellformat);
                                //cellFormat.Append(mergedCellformat);
                            }
                        }
```

[image]

The first sheet is perfect, it retains the formatting and its correct.
The rest of the sheets are all over the place with its formatting. Its not the same.

[image]

```
private static CellFormat GetCellFormat(WorkbookPart workbookPart, uint styleIndex)
{
    return workbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Elements<CellFormats>().First().Elements<CellFormat>().ElementAt((int)styleIndex);
}

private static uint InsertCellFormat(WorkbookPart workbookPart, CellFormat cellFormat)
{
    CellFormats cellFormats = workbookPart.WorkbookStylesPart.Stylesheet.Elements<CellFormats>().First();
    cellFormats.Append(cellFormat);
    return (uint)cellFormats.Count++;
}
```

Comment: Any time formatting is a key piece of the puzzle, pictures are appreciated. Could you add some images of the both the current (buggy) behavior and the expected behavior?

Comment: @Mikegrann Hi, the first image shows  the first sheet of the worksheet. Its retaining the same formatting and is fine. However the other sheets are not, the formatting is incorrect and is not being retained.

Comment: Can you show your `GetCellFormat` and `InsertCellFormat` methods please?

Comment: @petelids I have added them to the code above

Comment: I doubt it's your (entire) issue but the `return (uint)cellFormats.Count++;` looks wrong to me. That will return the `Count` and then increment the count _after_ it has been returned. Is this deliberate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can do this instead but I would try to attack this from the angle of selecting a range and using an OPENXML equivalent of the 'PasteSpecial' as referenced in the following:

[How to apply cell style to each cell in new row from previous row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29666074/how-to-apply-cell-style-to-each-cell-in-new-row-from-previous-row)

So, rather than trying to individually get the format, create the cell, fill the data and then copy format...

Define a source RangeSet.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.rangeset_members.aspx

CloneNode(true) of that.
Then insert that in the merged sheet. (as this should copy everything about the range including styling).

(Disclaimer: I haven't time to test this but hopefully the suggestion helps down an alternate pathway)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider creating a [Worksheet Template](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win016.htm).

Creating a new sheet using the template involves (VBA) code like this:

```
'Insert sheet template
With ThisWorkbook
    Set sh = Sheets.Add(Type:=Application.TemplatesPath & shName, _
                        after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
End With
```

then just fill it with raw data (whether through (VBA) `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues` or assigning values directly to cells) and name it.

The OpenXML equivalents for the above code should be easy enough to find.