# Auto expansion of formatted table in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop, formattable

I was trying to insert a new row at the end of a worksheet using OLEDB. The worksheet has a format table in a Range (a1:xx), with format and formula stored. But OLEDB insert does not come with any format.

I have read the post [How to copy format of one row to another row in Excel with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17716370/how-to-copy-format-of-one-row-to-another-row-in-excel-with-c-sharp) talking about get the format, but doesn't work for me. Also, I don't think it will get the formula.

In the Excel UI, at the lower right corner of a formatted table, a double arrow would appear, and we can drag it to expand the format table range.

[image: Image: What it looks like in the Excel]

Anything we could do through C#?

Thanks.

```
        Excel.Range last = xlWS.Cells.SpecialCells(Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
        Excel.Range RngToCopyOri = xlWS.get_Range("A1", last).EntireRow;
        Excel.Range RngToCopy = RngToCopyOri.Resize[RngToCopyOri.Rows.Count + 1, RngToCopyOri.Columns.Count]; //because insert will add only 1 row, so the range would be one row larger
        Excel.Range RngToInsert = xlWS.get_Range("A1", Type.Missing).EntireRow;
        RngToInsert.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, RngToCopy.Copy(Type.Missing));
```

I tried to copy Range(A1,lowerleft cell) to its original location, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried Range.resize, autofill, autoformat. All of them has sort of problems. I finally gave up using OLEDB to insert data. Instead, i used

```
worksheet.UsedRange.Item[rowNo,getColumnIndex(worksheet,columnTitle)]=value

private int getColumnIndex(Excel.Worksheet sheetname, string header) {
        int index=0;
        Excel.Range activeRange=sheetname.UsedRange;
        for (int i = 1; i <= activeRange.Columns.Count; i++) {
            if (header == (string)(activeRange.Item[1,i] as Excel.Range).Value) {
                index = i;
            }
        }
        if(index==0)
            throw some exception you like;
        return index;
    }
```

The getColumnIndex function aims to locate the column in SELECT [column] from...

In this way, the format table will automatically expand to the range you input the value.